# Is it possible to get the forgot password verification code through aws cli / boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm writing unit tests and in order to test the [forgot password](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html) flow, I need to get the verification code that is sent to the user's email through boto3 / aws cli. Can I get it with [GetUserAttributeVerificationCode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUserAttributeVerificationCode.html)? I can't find it on the cognito-idp docs.

Comment: Unit-Test why calling the "actual" function? Anyway, you can setup a test email and get confirmation code then.

Comment: How am I going to access the email programmatically?

Comment: Build a small program to pull an test email you design for your test case